# What is the symbol on a worker ahead sign?

Tags: usa, road-signs

I hope this is the correct place for this type of question.

I was wondering what the symbol on a US DOT W21-1a Worker Ahead road sign is.

My wife thinks it's a flagger with their flag down. I think it's a person digging.

Unfortunately, even though I can find everything else, including the dimensions of the image, I can't locate a description of what the image is supposed to be doing.

This is the image for reference:
[image: image of sign]

Official source please, if possible.

Comment: Digging but I never thought of looking for an official source. Maybe a driver's manual?

Comment: It indicates that there are construction workers on the road ahead. Because companies may be either government or independent, there are many sources for purchasing signs such as [this one](http://www.trafficsafetywarehouse.com/Construction-Signs/products/28/).(

Comment: There's a separate W20-7 "Flagger" sign that's meant to actually show a flagger (with flag up).

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to travel.

Comment: My father always called these "man having trouble putting up umbrella" which is even more fitting for the UK https://lisagawlas.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/men_at_work_sign.gif and Canada https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0181/7971/products/TC-2A_60X60_large.jpg?v=1355252173 ones

Comment: I assumed it was a small pile of road material that the person has to shovel onto the road.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel, but the design of road signs.

Comment: @mts Could you suggest another exchange site where it would have been a better fit?

Comment: @Drazisil I could not, and others seem to have disagreed with me, which is a good thing in the light of the answers you have received. The thing is, for some questions there is not yet an SE site. Something related to design would have been my guess, but no idea whether on-topic on [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: On the Swedish sign it is more clear that the man is digging: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Sweden_road_sign_A20.svg/250px-Sweden_road_sign_A20.svg.png

Comment: @mts Could you take it to meta so we can explicitly include or exclude it for the scope of Travel.se?

Comment: @Mast I don't see a reason to take this to meta unless we get swamped with this style of questions, however you are free to do so. I'm perfectly fine with how this stands right now.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here's the US Department of Transportation's official description from the [2009 MUTCD](https://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/htm/2009/part5/fig5g_01_longdesc.htm):

> W21-1 is shown as a diamond-shaped sign with a symbol of a right-facing person with a shovel digging.

Answer (score 25):

Its a person digging. Its based on the UK roadsign by Margaret Calvert (who inspired roadsigns across the world - see the German or Australian ones for the same).

She is [on record](http://flashbak.com/calvert-and-kinneirs-sign-design-classics-in-1965-british-roads-got-their-identity-38669/) as saying she wished she'd made the sign more shovel-like.

> She told Frieze: “I now regret that I didn’t put a corner of a spade
>   on the ‘men at work’ sign, it would have stopped all the jokes about a
>   man struggling to put up an umbrella!”

I guess its a salutary lesson about design, if its not 100% clear, its going to be confusing for all of future history!

Comment: The US version is a slight modification, and doesn't look much like an umbrella.